# Azure application gateway spring boot app VM scaleset

Tags: azure, azure-networking, springboot

I have a setup of Azure VM scaleset, each Linux VM running java spring boot app on a specific port (8070).
I need to use a domain with https on application gateway and use Linux VMSS with java app as backend pools.

I am aware this can be done with azure lb but I need to use SSL.
If this is possible with a gateway, what would be configurations for 'listeners', 'rules' and 'HTTP settings'

I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864688/azure-application-gateway-configuration/50867996#50867996) which is relevant to mine, but I need much more help.

[azure_app_gateway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZLxG.png)

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible with lb unless your app listens on https (so it needs a certificate). its possible to do SSL offloading on the app go or do end-to-end SSL. [this is the official article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal) to configure SSL offloading, [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell) is for e2e SSL.

basically, you need to create SSL and create a listener that's using that SSL certificate. probe behaviour doesn't change (compared to lb probe) unless you are doing e2e SSL.

Comment: I will go with ssl offloading on appgw. My problem how do I manage the http listener and rules and http settings for my VM scalesets which all have Java app running on 8070 port.

Comment: i dont see a question in your statement. read the official article. scale sets do not differ from vms in this regard

Comment: Yeah I see that , probably I didn't phrase my question properly. What would be the 'http settings' , 'rules' and 'listeners' if vmss run the app on 8070 port. How do I forward requests from appgw to vmss in terms of settings on appgw to be configured

Comment: follow the article and see for yourself? it tells you how to do that from scratch

Comment: I am afraid i also went through the (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-create-vmss-cli) but there's an example on nginx on vmss which runs on port 80, but is is possible i hit appgw on https://<appgw>.domain.com which hits backend pools on java app on port 8070.

What would be listener and http settings?

Comment: i dont understand, just change the port to 8070, how hard is that? create a sample appgw using those instructions and port 80 and just adjust them to port 8070. you'd need to change listener and probe